# Facebook Open Graph - Share Custom Story with Different Link

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have been banging my head for 3 days trying to solve this. Trust me, I have exhausted my stack overflow options, as well as various FB resources, so I suspect I am not understanding something.

I am using the Javascript SDK.

In short, my app needs to do the following:

- User lands on home page User fills out quizz
- Users can choose to share result to facebook
- Share on timeline says "User is an XXX type of person on MyApp"

I have set up a PHP page that dynamically generates my object meta tags as necessary. This is because I need the share title to include the persons name, and the type of personality they are, and therefore these two elements need to be dynamically generated and used in the generated meta tags.So far, so good.

The problem is this:

Every time I share my result, it shares the URL of where my dynamic object (PHP code is) and not the index page of my web site.

How can I get the sharer to share a link to the HOME PAGE, instead of the link to where my custom object code is. I have tried add href object properties, leaving out the og:url tag in the php generated meta, changing og:url to the desired share URL etc.

If I change og:url to my desired link I want shared, it then looks at that link for the image, title etc and NOT the php hosted custom property page.

Here is my FB.ui markup:

```
FB.ui({
    app_id: xxxxxxx,
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'helloweekend:is',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify(
    {
        weekend_person: "http://example.com/custom-object-page.php?og_personality=dummy&og_name=simon&og_track_id=123",
    }),
},
function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

The page at mydomain.com will generate the necessary  tags, and the result is ideal. The sharer will say "Simon is a dummy type person on xxx" and the image is set fine (as it is set dynamically).

It's only the end shared URL that I have a problem with, the one the suer is taken to when clicking the feed entry on their timeline, I would like to customize that.

Is this even possible, or does it mean that my object has to be present on the home page as well?

**EDIT**

In essence, I am actually sharing a story that does not really exist, and is a fictitious story created from the result of a quizz, ultimately referencing the home page.

Thank you in advance, 
Simon

Comment: That is not possible. Instead, redirect human visitors that follow the link to your Open Graph object from their Facebook feed to your index page, either client-side via JavaScript, or server-side (the latter would need an exception for the Facebook scraper, so that it will still read your meta data from the actually shared URL – see description of Like button for what User Agent it sends.)

Comment: @Cbroe - I suspected that this might be the case. Do you think it's also possible to shift the dynamic object generation page (currently it's own PHP script) onto the home page, or would you keep it on it's own page. My only gripe is that when the user hovers over the status on the timeline, they will see this not-so-attractive URL. I guess it's a small sacrifice. I'm being lazy here, but do you have any references to which URL scrapers I would need to exclude from my htaccess rules?

Comment: Well what other scrapers (besides the FB one) you’d need to exclude, would depend on what other services you want to be able to read the OG meta data as well (Google? Twitter? Plus whoever else might read and use those.) I’d probably just go with a JavaScript redirect here (plus a link/button to the homepage for the minority of users that has JS turned of.)

Comment: Right, got you. On second thoughts, based on the fact that this is a WordPress based web site, I could make the template for this custom open graph page the exact same as the home page. The trade off would be URL parameters being present, but hey, we can live with that?

Comment: It could even be beneficial if you let the user arrive on the shared URL first, and not redirect them to the homepage automatically. That way, on that page you could show them something like “User Foobar did take our quiz/test, and their result was […]”, plus an explicit call-to-action, “Take the test yourself!”. Being presented with what result their friend got makes it more personal, and could thus increase engagement.

Comment: @CBroe Your ideas definitely have merit. There is a lot of confusion over how the sharing on open graph works. Once sorted, I will updated my question to include my full solution. Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Yeah, do that. But don’t edit the solution into the question, but rather make it a [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) instead ;-)